# is it possible to declare a container of X as a member of X

Tags: c++

I have this class :

```
#include <unordered_map>

    class MyClass
    {
        // Trie node class
        struct Node
        {
            std::unordered_map<char, Node> m_children;
            // ...

        }; // .....
};
int main()
{
    MyClass m;
}
```

When compiling, I got this errors :

> /usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_pair.h:204:11: error: ‘std::pair<_T1,
>   _T2>::second’ has incomplete type
>          _T2 second;                /// @c second is a copy of the second object
>              ^~~~~~ AutocompleteModern.cpp:24:12: note: forward declaration of ‘struct Autocomplete::Node’
>        struct Node
>               ^~~~

I know that if I use a pointer as a value in the hash map, this might work. But I wonder if it's possible to make the code above compile without changing the type the hash map's value. or is it impossible ?

Comment: You don't need to be a c++ expert Start with  providing a [mcve] that reproduces your problem please.

Comment: It is quite common here that people do downvotes without any constructive comments. Sometimes only cause they self did not understand the question... I can't see any problems with your question. The sense of SO is to ask for unknown things ;) The posted code you provide is self explaining and the question is understandable. No reason for a downvote from my perspective!

Comment: @Klaus I disagree. We have the [mcve] policy here for reasons.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: For what reason? As I already said: I understand the question and the code explains the problem well. There is no need to do own compilation to improve the code or get the error message on own system. User asks for a general topic of c++ and this is well formulated here. So the code presented is minimal and any additional code to make it compilable ( including some main etc ) will not clarify anything but waste space and readers time. But I will not start a discussion here... It is up to you to stay at your position.

Comment: @Klaus: the compiler (if it was run by the OP) would complain. And then the OP should improve his code to get it compilable. So he won't ask the question.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Can't catch your point, sorry. Most of my own questions are started at the point where the compiler complains about something. The problem is not to see *that* something is wrong, but we need sometimes help from more experienced users to get the answer for *why* the compiler complains. If everybody is able to fix all issues simply by following up the compilers errros... we can shutdown SO? Maybe I misunderstand your point, I am not a native speaker...

Comment: My intuition is that the OP would find in a few seconds that what he is trying to code is rejected by the compiler. But imagine 100 persons are taking one second each to simply *read* the question: that is 100 seconds of person-time lost. Why would that be preferable to the few seconds the OP would need to try on his compiler? Why is our (collective) time worth less than the OP's time?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch - this question, as originally posted, included an error message from the compiler, and was asking about why.    In a subsequent edit, the code sample has become code which would have triggered that error.

Comment: @Klaus If you click on the link you'll find out why we require MCVEs for debugging questions. This is not optional. Every single day we waste collective _hours_ asking people for MCVEs because they didn't bother to follow the instructions and provide one, and 80% of the time, the error was in the code they thought was not relevant. It's a waste of everybody's freely-provided time. If you do not like the policy, you are free to use a different website. Thanks.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - late night here, working through some complicated study problems.  Fun, but obviously I'm getting tired.   Please disregard last comments;  I've deleted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible for *some* containers, but `std::unordered_map` is not one of them. It *might* work with some implementations, but the standard doesn't require it to work for `std::unordered_map` (in fact it says its undefined to do it). So even if it compiled today, with a particular compiler, it might not work tomorrow.

The containers that can be declared with incomplete types are `std::forward_list`, `std::list`, and `std::vector`. So those containers can be used as a member of a class, before the class definition is complete)

Comment: Great answer, but you could improve it by citing the C++ standard (which I admit you know better than I do); where in the standard is it mentioned to be "undefined behavior" ?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I could, but it wouldn't help much, because the relevant rules are subtle and unclear. It's undefined to instantiate **any** standard library template with an incomplete type unless specified otherwise (see [res.on.functions] p2 bullet (2.5)), and those three containers specify otherwise ([forwardlist.overview] p4, [list.overview] p3, and [vector.overview] p3).

Comment: I'm really impressed by that comment. Someone knowing enough the C++ standard to be able to say that some rule is unclear in it. I am even more curious about that rule! (I did glance in the C++ standard a few times, but I have decided it is too complex for me)

Comment: Once again, `std::vector` for the win!

Answer (score 5):

You have a circular loop dependency: You say that `m_children` should contain `Node` objects, but at that point the class `Node` isn't defined (only *declared*).

You could use *pointers* (or references) to incomplete types though:

```
std::unordered_map<char, std::unique_ptr<Node>> m_children;
```

Note the use of [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr), which is used to indicate that the map is the sole owner of the `Node` objects (and also has the added benefit of some automatic memory management).

Comment: OK, clear, I will use std::unordered_map<char, Node&> (I never thought it was possible to use & with containers).

Comment: @Aminos _"I will use std::unordered_map<char, Node&>"_ That will leave you with _troubles_ also.

Comment: @Aminos *That's* not possible though, since most containers requires their data to be copyable, which references aren't. While there are [ways around it](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref), pointers are usually the best way to go here.

Comment: I will go with std::ref

Comment: I think I will go with unique_ptr finally, as I need to insert nodes in the hash map and if I create them in stack, I will have undefined behavior later...

Answer (score 2):

> But I wonder if it's possible to make the code above compile without changing the type the hash map's value. or is it impossible ?

It is impossible, because the compiler cannot compute a meaningful (and finite) `sizeof` for that `MyClass`.

Put yourself in the compiler shoes: it has to compute a layout, and a byte size (as given by `sizeof`) for `MyClass` quite early when compiling your code. And it obviously could not.

In C++, for such circularity, you *have to use pointers* (but you could "hide" them as smart pointers, etc.).

(So this answer is a rationale or an intuition for [Some programmer dude's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54052254/841108))

There is also another (purely "legal") reason: the C++11 standard [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) forbids that. I leave up to you to check (and find precisely what clause there forbids that).

PS. As commented by [songyanyo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3309790/songyuanyao), you might find [some](https://wandbox.org/permlink/mIVvHAXUBamHCVBh) *particular* [C++ standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Standard_Library) implementation where your code is accepted (I guess that on such implementations, more hidden pointers are used). This is not the case on my Linux Debian Sid box (both with GCC 8 and Clang 7). In practice you want to write code that is compilable on your box. I have no idea which particular C++ standard library is the most conforming to the standard, but the intuition above stays.